# Unable to create a role when using ACCOUNTADMIN or SYSADMIN in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task

I am getting the error *"SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on account 'XXXXXX'"* when I try to create a role in Snowflake in order to get it connected to Segment.

I am following the Segment documentation here: https://segment.com/docs/connections/warehouses/catalog/snowflake/

And I am getting stuck when I run the command "`CREATE ROLE "SEGMENT";`"

Any help in how to get around this would be great. I am currently on the trial and was able to successfully create the data warehouse and database as per the segment instructions.

Comment: Are you explicitly setting your role as ACCOUNTADMIN (i.e use role accountadmin;) before trying this? Do you have access to the SECURITYADMIN role and if so could you try creating the role with that?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Greg in the comments:
"An easy way to remember it is that the upper right role is for UI actions, while the lower one sets the context for the worksheet"

1) while I had the correct profile up here

2) once I clicked this

3) I did not have the right profile in here

After switching to ACCOUNTADMIN in 3) I was able to create the role.

[screenshot of how I fixed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxVEf.png)

Comment: This is the #1 most common mistake made when choosing roles in the Snowflake UI.

Comment: Was surprised that there was no questions about this already or at least not that came up with a quick google. If you have any recommendations on how I could change the title of the question for it to be better found through search let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. An easy way to remember it is that the upper right role is for UI actions, while the lower one sets the context for the worksheet.